# What is the minimum degree of x so that it is greater than or equal to ln(x)?

Tags: logarithms

I was thinking of this question and couldn't find it anywhere. I was trying to find a solution by finding the maximum of the function $f(x) = \frac{ln(ln(x))}{ln(x)}$,
 yet I'm not sure if that's gonna work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this by using calculus:

Let $$f(x) = \frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}$$

Then, taking the derivative:

$$f'(x)  = \frac{1-\ln(\ln(x))}{x\ln^2(x)}$$

Setting it equal to 0 to find the maximum value:

$$\frac{1-\ln(\ln(x))}{x\ln^2(x)} = 0$$
$$1-\ln(\ln(x)) = 0$$
$$\ln(x) = e$$
$$x = e^e$$

Our maximum value occurs when $x = e^e$
Plugging this back into our function:
$$f(e^e) = \frac{\ln(\ln(e^e))}{\ln(e^e)}$$
$$f(e^e) = \frac{1}{e}$$